# Creating A Channel In A Certain Category

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(description=f"**{ctx.author.name} Has Created a Ticket**")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    category_channel = client.get_channel(724344480458604644)
    await guild.create_text_channel(f'{ctx.author.name}-ticket', catergory=category_channel)
```

I'm creating a ticket system that I'll modify later but I can't find a way to get a category. The code above doesn't work but it doesn't have any errors.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a category by just using the category attribute of a channel. (You also mis-spelt category in the `create_text_channel` bit.)

```
@client.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(description=f"**{ctx.author.name} Has Created a Ticket**")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    category_channel = channel.category
    await guild.create_text_channel(f'{ctx.author.name}-ticket', category=category_channel)
```